# read csv file from s3 using lambda using java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

```
public class LambdaFunctionHandler implements RequestHandler<S3Details, List<Map<String, String>>> {

    private AmazonS3 s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().build();

    public LambdaFunctionHandler() {}

    // Test purpose only.
    LambdaFunctionHandler(AmazonS3 s3) {
        this.s3 = s3;
    }

    public List<Map<String, String>> handleRequest(S3Details event, Context context)  {
        context.getLogger().log("Received event: " + event);

        // Get the object from the event and show its content type
        String bucket = event.getBucketName();
        String key = event.getObjectKey();
        List<Map<String, String>> listKeyVals = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            S3Object response = s3.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucket, key));
            byte[] byteArray = IOUtils.toByteArray(response.getObjectContent());

            Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray));
            Iterator<Map<String, String>> iterator= new CsvMapper().readerFor(Map.class)
            .with(CsvSchema.emptySchema().withHeader())
            .readValues(reader);
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Map<String,String> keyVals = iterator.next();
            listKeyVals.add(keyVals);
            
        } }

            catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            context.getLogger().log(String.format(
                "Error getting object %s from bucket %s. Make sure they exist and"
                + " your bucket is in the same region as this function.", key, bucket));
           
        }
        return listKeyVals;
      
    }
}
```

using JSON passing bucket name and CSV filename
I have converted the object to byte array then tried to read CSV file line by line
I have to read csv file from s3 bucket using lambda

Comment: You forgot to define your issue. Any errors? What are you asking for?